# prevent mobile detection on browser reload event

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, subdomain, detection

I'm using wordpress and I have one domain and one subdomain: mysite.com and m.mysite.com.

When a visitor see my site on a mobile, I'm using the next chunck of code to redirect him to the subdomain:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = “http://m.mysite.com/”;
}
</script>
```

I'm using the same database for the domain and the subdomain. They share the posts data but they have 2 different design (jquery mobile for m.mysite.com). Also some page exist only on mysite.com.

So, if a visitor go to my site from a desktop browser, resize his browser under 699 px, reload the page, I don't want to redirect him to the mobile subdomain. What is the best way to do this?  Thanks

Comment: try window.location.href = "http://m.mysie.com";

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `window.location` as opposed to `document.location` given internet explorer's garbage design. Then test to see if the existing domain is already `m.mysite.com`

```
if (screen.width <= 699 && window.location.indexOf('m.mysite.com') < 1) {
    window.location = “http://m.mysite.com/”;
}
```

This will ensure that it doesn't redirect over and over.

Comment: thanks but if a visitor go to my site from a desktop browser, resize his browser under 699 px, reload the page, I don't want to redirect him to the mobile subdomain.

Comment: @Frank Then you should probably use a feature detection library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), otherwise you'll be reinventing the wheel, which seems silly.